# Update a select's options based on another dropdown, using React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, select, react-hooks, jsx

I've got 2 selects in my form. Options for the 2nd select are generated based on 1st select. Everything works fine except that every time I choose an option for the 2nd select and then change the 1st one, I should get the default option for the 2nd, but it's not resetting.

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Code below

```js
  const [animalClass, setAnimalClass] = useState();
  const [animalType, setAnimalType] = useState();

  const [isLoadingClasses, setLoadingClasses] = useState(true);
  const [isLoadingTypes, setLoadingTypes] = useState(true);
  const [availableAnimalClasses, setAvailableAnimalClasses] = useState();
  const [availableAnimalTypes, setAvailableAnimalTypes] = useState();
 
  useEffect(() => {
    setLoadingClasses(true);
    const availableOptions = async () => {
      const availableClasses = await Axios.get();
      console.log(availableClasses.data);
      if (availableClasses.data.length > 0) {
        setAvailableAnimalClasses(availableClasses.data.map(animal => ({name: animal.name})));
        setLoadingClasses(false);
      }
    };
    availableOptions();
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
    setLoadingTypes(true);
    setAnimalType("DEFAULT");
    const availableOptions = async () => {
      const availableTypes = await Axios.get();
      console.log(availableTypes.data);
      if(availableTypes.data.length > 0) {
        setAvailableAnimalTypes(availableTypes.data.map(animal => ({name: animal.name})));
        setLoadingTypes(false);
      }
    };
    availableOptions();
  }, [animalClass]);

  return (
    <div className="page">
    <h2>New Auction</h2>
    <form className="form" onSubmit={onSubmit}>
      <label>
      Animal Class
        <select defaultValue={'DEFAULT'} onChange={(e) => setAnimalClass(e.target.value)} >
          <option value="DEFAULT" disabled>Choose animal class</option>
          {isLoadingClasses ? <option value="Loading" disabled>Loading.....</option> :  availableAnimalClasses.map((option) => (
            <option value={option.name}>{upperCase(option.name)}</option>
          ))}
        </select>
      </label>
      <label>Animal Type
        <select defaultValue={'DEFAULT'} onChange={(e) => setAnimalType(e.target.value)} >
          <option value="DEFAULT" disabled>Choose animal type</option>
          {isLoadingTypes? <option value="Loading" disabled>Loading.....</option> :  availableAnimalTypes.map((option) => (
            <option value={option.name}>{upperCase(option.name)}</option>
          ))}
        </select>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are using state to store your form field values, you could set your defaults when you create the hooks:

```js
const [animalClass, setAnimalClass] = useState('DEFAULT');
const [animalType, setAnimalType] = useState('DEFAULT');
```

and then use `value` instead of `defaultValue` in your JSX:

```
<select value={animalClass} onChange={(e) => setAnimalClass(e.target.value)} >
...
<select value={animalType} onChange={(e) => setAnimalType(e.target.value)} >
```

These values should reset your select elements when the state changes.

Answer (score -1):

You should call `setAnimalType` to reset it back to the default when selecting the animal class. Change:

```
<select defaultValue={'DEFAULT'} onChange={(e) => setAnimalClass(e.target.value)}>...</select>
```

...to:

```
<label>
  Animal Class
  <select
    defaultValue={'DEFAULT'}
    value={animalClass}
    onChange={(e) => {
      setAnimalClass(e.target.value);
      setAnimalType('DEFAULT');
    }}
  >
    ...
  </select>
</label>
<label>
  Animal Type
  <select
    defaultValue={'DEFAULT'}
    value={animalType}
    onChange={(e) => setAnimalType(e.target.value)}
  >
    // ...
  </select>
</label>
```

This is necessary because the `onChange` event will not be automatically fired for a `select` when the options change. In order for this to work, where state controls the state of your `<select/>`s, you'll also want to change `the` defaultValue`props to`value` props.

Comment: Ah, missed that you were using `defaultValue` instead of `value`. That'd be why.